# Filter list view by people picker column

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SharePoint online, we can filter  `list web part` using a `text filter web part`.
In a similar way, how can I create a `people picker` type of filter which will filter the list.

Is it possible Out of the box?

Comment: Do you mean that when you try to filter and pick a Person&Group column, you would like to get a People Picker field for picking the users you would like to filter on? Why not just type their names?

Comment: I have to search the person with their user name, I can do this using simple text filter webpart, but if it is a people picker type textbox then advantage is that it will also validate if that username is valid

Comment: I see what you mean now. Why not simply use the column filter like in Excel instead of an additional webpart: click the column name and then select the name of the user?

Comment: The requirement is different here, user needs to search item based on the username, its UI requirement